# How to copy Wikipedia formulas to Libreoffice Math?

Tags: libreoffice

We can get into Wikipedia formula's code, but how do we read it on libreoffice Math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia uses the **LaTeX** format for formulas.

**LaTeX** is a popular and powerful language for formatting documents and formulas, and there is a variety of software for Ubuntu that can help edit it, including **LyX** and **TeXStudio** and **Kile**.

LibreOffice Math does not normally support LaTeX equations, but there's an extension for LibreOffice called **[TexMaths](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/texmaths-1)** that will allow you to use LaTeX formulas, such as those used on Wikipedia, inside LibreOffice Math.

However, TeXMaths unfortunately does not appear to be available (yet) for the latest 5.x versions of LibreOffice.

Please let me know if this answer was helpful or if you have further questions.

--Nick

Comment: I thought it was mathml. I would like to convert latex formulas to libreoffice math, but I think it's not possible.

Comment: Wikipedia itself says it uses LaTeX; please see this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution is to convert the LaTeX code to MathML format and then import the code to Libreoffice Math.
Lots of conversion tool available. Link for two such tools are given below

[Online converter](https://www.mathtowebonline.com/)

[itex2MML](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/blog/itex2MML.html)

After the conversion copy the generated code and open Libreoffice math, then goto tool menu> import MathML from clipboard.